Hubspot API - Media Bridge Object Definitions - 488
I am developing an app for Hubspot CMS. It will use media bridge and media objects.
I am trying to define a media object and I am having a generic (and weird) error 488.
I am sending the following request:
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.hubapi.com/media-bridge/v1/{MY_APP_KEY}/settings/object-definitions?hapikey={MY_DEVELOPER_KEY}' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "mediaTypes": ["OTHER"]
}'


And the response error (488) is:
{ "status": "error", "message": "There was a problem with the request.", "correlationId": "2160d33c-accf-48ed-b0c3-136f5a0f2410" }

I could not find any support for this error in the Hubspot community and documentation.

The Hubspot team solved the error. Now it is working!
